Is it possible to get md5 of the entire table in SQL Server? E.g., by hashbytes
We want to get the md5 checksum of the entire table to verify the consistency of data, e.g. using the hashbytes() function of SQL Server.
As an intermediate step in the proof of concept, we figured out a way to concatenate all the columns into one single text string, so we can get the md5 checksum of each row of the table. Please see the following sample SQL as an example.
select
  hashbytes('md5',
    ''
    + col_1
    + col_2
      ...
    + col_n
    + char(0)+char(0)+char(13)+char(10)
  )
from the_table
;

However, we wonder how to get the md5 checksum of the entire table.
Ideally, we want to run md5sum on the input source text file, and hope to match with the md5 checksum from the imported database table.
And we highly appreciate any hints and suggestions.

"Ideally, we want to run md5sum on the input source text file, and hope to match with the md5 checksum from the imported database table." That's never gonna happen. A database table is much more than just a csv file, and will store things somewhat different. Things like date values have their own internal format, text collations will be different (UCS2 by default in SQL Server instead of UTF-8). It's just not gonna work how you want.

While i agree with @JoelCoehoorn's comment, the specific md5 hash of a table can be answered in some ways.
Note that even if you get md5 of a table, you need to consider things like NULLs vs empty strings vs spaces, nvarchar vs varchar, different stylizations of FLOATS, numerics etc etc. Note also that file usually have new lines and column separators, which of course is translated into rows in the db.
One easy way of creating md5 is doing it through a FOR JSON intermediary:
select HASHBYTES('md5', (
   select *
   from sys.objects
   order by object_id
   for json path, include_null_values)
  )

Note that this creates a USC-2 string of a jsonfied table content, which has different characteristics than plain ASCII or UTF8/16 when HASHBYTES is concerned. So when you do your file, you need to use same techniques when creating json content.
You could also try to mimic the file content itself by doing something like:
select HASHBYTES('md5', (
   select CONCAT(name, CHAR(9), object_id, CHAR(9), schema_id, CHAR(10))
   from sys.objects
   order by object_id for xml path(''),type).value('text()[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)')
  )

This creates a tab separated "file" string with \n as row separator which is then MD5ed. Here i'm using FOR XML "trick" which allows creating text blob from table easy. Note that you need to manually build the "columns" by doing CONCAT function call.
So yeah, while it's technically possible, there are a lot of challenges to getting content match up. Usually, it's better to do some kind of manual hash where you compare row count, some key metrics like SUMs etc to make sure what you have imported match what you wanted to import in the first place
